# Error shown for Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object in Wordpress After Content for User Roles

Tags: plugins, php, user-roles, html, the-content

I have been struggling to code a function, which echoes a code, when the user role is `'administrator'` or is `um_verified'`

Honestly I don't know much of what it means, but still, I want to solve this problem. This function picks up the user id for the given WordPress post, then gets the author data, using the Author Data it finds out the user role, and if the user role matched the if clause, it echoes it, the whole functions run after content.

My implementation of the code which is given below gives the correct result, basically works, but it shows an error of "Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object" basically which means that the property should be an object.

How can I solve the error, basically I know something is wrong because it piles up about 5mb of errors in just a matter of a few hours. Please help me correct the code, and also, please explain what does an object means in PHP.

```
function Milyin_After_Content($content) { 
        if( is_single() ):
        ob_start();

     $user_meta=get_userdata(get_the_author_meta('ID'));
 $user_role=$user_meta->roles;
if (in_array("administrator", $user_role) | in_array("um_verified", $user_role)){
    echo '<svg height="12pt" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="12pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m256 0c-141.164062 0-256 114.835938-256 256s114.835938 256 256 256 256-114.835938 256-256-114.835938-256-256-256zm0 0" fill="#1f1fff"/><path d="m385.75 201.75-138.667969 138.664062c-4.160156 4.160157-9.621093 6.253907-15.082031 6.253907s-10.921875-2.09375-15.082031-6.253907l-69.332031-69.332031c-8.34375-8.339843-8.34375-21.824219 0-30.164062 8.339843-8.34375 21.820312-8.34375 30.164062 0l54.25 54.25 123.585938-123.582031c8.339843-8.34375 21.820312-8.34375 30.164062 0 8.339844 8.339843 8.339844 21.820312 0 30.164062zm0 0" fill="#fff"/></svg>  
    ';}
        $code_content_2 = ob_get_clean();
        $content .= $code_content_2;
        endif;
        return $content;
    }

add_filter('the_content', 'Milyin_After_Content_2', 10);
```

This is the code, and the code that I echo is just the normal HTML, basically the SVG tag, so there should not be a problem with it. If there exists a better approach or a built-in Wordpress function to check for an array of user roles, then that would be even better, but as this was the only method I found, please help me debug it, and improve it...

Comment: I don't get that error using your code (with a couple of fixes: two pipes || instead of one, and adding your current function name instead of the _2 function name). Is it possible you still have two functions and you forgot to hook the correct one, so the one you're not intending to use is still in use, and this version that does work without errors just isn't running?

Comment: Well ya that 2 was a typo, and i shall surely use ||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object in PHP is a data type that you can read more [data types here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-data-types.php)

It's good practice to check variable types before using them. In your case, you are assuming `$user_meta` is an object. Since you are filtering `the_content()`, it might be called some place else and returning that error.

Here is your code updated with `is_object()` to check on that variable before you use it:

```
function Milyin_After_Content($content) { 
  if( is_single() ):
    ob_start();

    $user_meta=get_userdata(get_the_author_meta('ID'));

    // NOTE: 
    // First check
    if(is_object($user_meta)){

      // Then set your variable here
      $user_role=$user_meta->roles;

      if (in_array("administrator", $user_role) || in_array("um_verified", $user_role)){
        echo '<svg height="12pt" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="12pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m256 0c-141.164062 0-256 114.835938-256 256s114.835938 256 256 256 256-114.835938 256-256-114.835938-256-256-256zm0 0" fill="#1f1fff"/><path d="m385.75 201.75-138.667969 138.664062c-4.160156 4.160157-9.621093 6.253907-15.082031 6.253907s-10.921875-2.09375-15.082031-6.253907l-69.332031-69.332031c-8.34375-8.339843-8.34375-21.824219 0-30.164062 8.339843-8.34375 21.820312-8.34375 30.164062 0l54.25 54.25 123.585938-123.582031c8.339843-8.34375 21.820312-8.34375 30.164062 0 8.339844 8.339843 8.339844 21.820312 0 30.164062zm0 0" fill="#fff"/></svg>';
      }
      $code_content_2 = ob_get_clean();
      $content .= $code_content_2;
    }

  endif;

  return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'Milyin_After_Content_2', 10);
```

(Also note @WebElaine's comment above, you should be using two pipes in that if() statement.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi there, I did as suggested in the comments, and further on tried your code. Your code runs, but another problem has emerged, it says undefined variable user_role in the wordpress debug log... What can we do to solve it...

Comment: The second `if` statement depends on `$user_role` existing - and it only exists if `$user_meta` is an object. So, moving the second `if` statement inside the first will solve this issue.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, I've update the above snippet to fix that issue, give that a try? WebElaine pointed out an oversight I made.

Comment: Yep, WebElaine and ChristopherJones, thank you to both for helping me, currently the code runs and there are no errors reported, just in case i find some problem in it, i shall contact you guys again. Thanks for support anyway.. :-)